# Defining functions from nameless namespace outside the namespace

Tags: c++, scope, linker

If I declare a class inside a nameless namespace, but define the member functions outside that nameless namespace, like so:

```
A.hpp:
    namespace {

        struct A{
            A();
        };
    }

A1.cpp:
    A::A()
    {
        std::cout << "hello from A1";
    }

A2.cpp
    A::A()
    {
        std::cout << "hello from A2";
    }
```

will the defined functions be visible from other translation units during linking? Am I violating the ODR if I link `A1.o` and `A2.o` into one executable?

Comment: Nameless namespaces are considered `private` inside compilation units, and hidden from linking outside.

Comment: What about functions that are defined outside of them though

Comment: To declare A outside of the nameless namespace, you have to have A outside of the `namespace { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: member functions (static or not) of a class have the linkage of the class. Here the class has internal linkage, so for all its functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` has internal linkage because it belongs to an unnamed namespace. All its member functions, including `A::A`, consequently also have internal linkage. There is no way to change that and it is not dependent on how often or where you declare (or define) the member functions. The linkage of member functions is always derived from the linkage of the class they belong to.

Comment: Is this something you know a cite for? I sure hope you're right, it would make several problems I have easier, but I really need to know if this is standards-guaranteed or "works on my machine."

Comment: @SRNissen https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#link-5